# Visual Studio: Publishing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-c++

Please could somebody give me a brief definition of what it means to `publish` a Visual Studio project? Both for an ASP.NET website, and a C++ application. For the C++ application, the .exe file is already created during the build operation, so what does publishing provide in addition to this? I cannot find any definitions anywhere, formal or informal, only tutorials on actually how to do it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish it just puts the files in the place you configure, remote server or whatever.